# MS SQL Creating Tables and Adding Values by a Trigger

Tags: sql-server, trigger, update, insert, table

Table_A is an existing table which has 3 columns Id (PK), Name, Stock.
I would like to create a trigger to create a table.

For example, Table_A has an item, Id (PK) = 3, Name = Apple, Stock = 10.
By using triggers I would like to create a new table called Table_B and when I write the following code "INSERT INTO Table_B VALUES(3,5)" a new table will be created and it will have 2 columns ProductId and Quanity. At the same time the value for Stock for Table_A will be decreased by 5. Every time I insert something to Table_B I would like them to get added to Table_B and the stock in Table_A to be decreased by the quantity of that item inserted with the related ProductId. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please clarify your goals a little bit better? For example, using actual table names (even if you just call them `TableA`, `TableB`, and `TableC`) when you reference each event you want to occur will make your question immensely easier to follow.

Comment: I edited it. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `[Product]` table and a `[ProductTransaction]` table, and your goal is to have `[Product].[Quantity]` always be the sum of the transaction table, then your trigger will need to take into account `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` operations. You will also need to ensure that nobody ever directly updates the `[Product].[Quantity]` value, as it will result in inconsistencies.

One way to get around this without using a trigger would be to use a view. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_inventory AS
SELECT p.[ID], p.[Name], SUM(txn.[Quantity]) AS [Quantity]
  FROM [Product] p INNER JOIN [ProductTransaction] txn ON p.[ID] = txn.[ProductID]
 GROUP BY p.[ID], p.[Name]
```

Then you can query off the view:

```
SELECT * FROM [vw_inventory]
 WHERE [ID] = 4;
```

Otherwise, if you *really* want to use a trigger, then you'll need to set an `AFTER` trigger on the transaction table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [trg_product_quantity]
    ON [ProductTransaction]
 AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
    AS
 BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE [Product] p 
       SET [Quantity] = tmp.[Quantity]
      FROM (SELECT z.[ProductID], SUM(z.[Quantity]) as [Quantity]
              FROM [ProductTransaction] txn 
             WHERE txn.[ProductID] IN (inserted.[ProductID], deleted.[ProductID])
             GROUP BY z.[ProductID]) tmp 
     WHERE tmp.[ProductID] = p.[ID];
   END
```

> **Note:** Be sure to double-check and modify this SQL code. I may have mixed in a little MySQL/PostgreSQL by mistake.

Hope this gives you something to think about